# What's the difference between using @BeforeClass and using instance or static variable in JUnit 4 Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I'm new to unit test. About the purpose of using `@Before` annotation in **JUnit 4**. I just don't know the point of using it:

```
public class FoodTestCase {
    static private Food sandwich;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialise(){
        sandwich = new Sandwich();    
    }

}
```

vs

```
public class FoodTestCase {
    static private Food sandwich = new Sandwich();

}
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea is like that:
You use @AfterClass to free resources. Then it is logical to have @BeforeClass to acquire them. Because it may not be a good idea to let developer to guess that he need to use static block.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it may not be necessary, as the initialization is really simple.

In case you have some logging, complex initialization or need to free some resources, you have to use [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and [@AfterClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html)

Comment: You can use static block to do that initialization. static { ... } The only different case is when your initializing code throws checked exception

Comment: What about freeing resources ? You can't do that in a static block. Well, you can, but not when it's really needed.

Comment: You can acquire resources in static block and use finalize(). Not the best approach. JUnit API allows developer to know less java and write better code)

Answer (score 2):

Almost no difference. But if constructor of `Sandwich` throws exception you cannot initialize it directly `static private Food sandwich = new Sandwich();` but have to wrap initialization with `try/catch` block. However method `initialise()` may be declared as `throws MyException`, so the test case will fail if exception indeed thrown during initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you had all of your Food related data (say a Menu) setup at the backend in a database table. Your Food test cases could then pertain to updating the Menu (all the CRUD ops basically).

Instead of opening a DB connection for every test case (using `@Before`); it would be wise if you do it just ***once*** before you run all your test cases via a method marked `@BeforeClass`.

Now the use of a method makes sense as the ***setup*** would most probably be slightly complex (you may decide to use a Spring container to get your `Connection` from a `DataSource`) and you would not be able to achieve it with a single line where you declare your `Connection` object.

Similarly, you would use the `@AfterClass` to ***tear down*** your global setup (for all the test cases) i.e. closing your database connection here.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example - not much. However there is also @Before annotation which will run prior to every test in your class. Take a look at http://selftechy.com/2011/05/17/junit4-before-vs-beforeclass-after-vs-afterclass, it is explained well there.

Answer (score 0):

`@BeforeClass` is for static initializations.

Instances created here will be reused across all of your `@Test` s

Whereas `@Before` is per `@Test` .

Usually `@BeforeClass` is reserved for objects which are relatively expensive to instantiate.
 e.g. Database connections

Answer (score 0):

### Inheritance adds another wrinkle:

Let's say you have two JUnit tests that extend a common base class.
And let's say the base class has both a static initializer block *and* a `@BeforeClass` method.
In this case, the static initializer block will run **once**, while the `@BeforeClass` method will run **twice**.

So, if you have a *very* expensive computation or resource that you need set up across a whole *suite* of test cases that share a common base class, then you could use the static initializer block for that.